# Color Text Search in syncfusion DataGridView C#

Tags: c#, windows, syncfusion

I want color the given search text in the DataGridView in syncfusion. I have tried but there highlight only not color of text.

The following image I want to make similar but by using DataGridView in syncfusion:

[image]

but following image that there in syncfusion:
[image]

Comment: I wait the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it’s not possible to change the foreground color of font while searching the words in SfDataGrid.

Regards, 
Susmitha S